# Make equations large

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize

I'm including some equations in my document, but want them to appear very large. I have them in display mode, as opposed to inline mode, but can't seem to find any way to make them larger.

I've tried using `\huge` but that seems to make all of the text in that section large (even when using it with {'s).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Two thoughts come to mind.

Put a `\scalebox` command from the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package

```
\[ \scalebox{2}{$\displaystyle 2 + 2 = 4$} \]
```

will make an equation twice as big as normal. `\displaystyle` forces the same display needed under `\[`...`\]`, since `$`...`$` would normally use `\textstyle` (cause operators to act differently).

Another option would be to use the `\mathlarger` and `\mathsmaller` commands from the [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package.

I'm sure there are other options too.

Answer (score 19):

You could use `\DeclareMathSizes` to specify the font sizes for math mode. The first argument is a text size, the further arguments set the corresponding math sizes in display/text style, script style and scriptscript style.

**Example:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{30}{16}{12}
\begin{document}
\noindent
This is regular text. An equation should be really big:
\[
    2x^2 + y^{2^2} = 1
\]
The text continues.
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

So, by just one command you may adjust the math font sizes consistently for all styles.

Comment: Didn't know about `\DeclareMathSizes`. This is interesting, but can only be used in the preamble, so it affects _all_ the math. Moreover, my comment to Will's answer also applies: If you use the default CM fonts then it doesn't work for large operators such as `\int`.

Comment: This can be repaired for integrals by loading the `esint` package. Loading `exscale` allows scaling of the standard math extension font `cmex` and results in larger `\int` and `\sum` symbols.

Comment: I was hoping that this allows for changing display math size only; but as said in the answer, the second argument controls "display/text style", _both_. It may be good to update the example to reflect this, maybe as in: "... is regular text (but see $a^{2}$). An equation should ..."

Comment: Good solution except if \text{} is used inside equations (they get uneven). In this case, for the whole document, [this seems a better option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160440/26430).

Answer (score 8):

This example doesn't work with the default CM fonts, but `\Huge` and friends should be able to do the job for you. Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\section{foo}
some text
{\Huge\[
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx
\]}%
more text
\section{bar}
more text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would add that it does work with the default CM fonts as long as you don't use large operators such as `\int`.

Answer (score 2):

Altought the question is old I add a solution usinig `scalerel` package to increase the size of a formula:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\begin{document}
I'm using scalerel package to increase a formula
\[\scaleto{2x^2 + y^{2^2} = 1}{30pt}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]